# LocalDateTime not working - without any kind of error

Tags: java, logging

I'm developing a Java project, a log analyzer, that imports any kind of log informations in a universal way.
Actually, I divided any log sheet in a Log class instance, and any sheet line in a Event class instance.
The problem is:  Log read all the sheet, and instance an Event with every read line, putting it in a LinkedHashSet.
When Event gets constructed, it takes - depending on which Log type is it in - all the informations (such as the time the event happened).
Everything works flawlessly, except for getting Date/Time from event string.

In fact, without any kind of error, Log's adding Event cycle, stops.
Deleting every Time-related line, I correctly manage to get everything: with them, it stops, without any error, but making me getting only bunch of lines, instead of the thousands I should get.

Here you can find Log and Event classes, and even the method that gets Time from event and the last line of Event the manage to get Time and the first one that doesn't.

Log:

```
public class Log {

    /** LogType assigned to log file */
    private LogType type;

    /** filename associated to log file*/
    private String name;

    /** path associated to log file */
    private String path;

    private LinkedHashSet<Evento> events;


    /**
     * Log constructor:
     * @param path points to file which create log instance from
     * @param type is the LogType type associated with the rising Log
     * @param bInitialize indicates if Log has to initialize events list
     */
    public Log(String path, LogType type, boolean bInitialize) {
        String[] pathComponents = path.split("/");
        this.path = path;
        this.type = type;
        this.name = pathComponents[pathComponents.length - 1];
        populateEvents();
    }

    public LinkedHashSet<Evento> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    /** type field getter */
    public LogType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /** name field getter */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /** path field getter */
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    /** @return path field */
    public String toString() {
        return path;
    }

    public TreeSet<Utente> getUsers() {
        TreeSet<Utente> users = new TreeSet<Utente>();
        for (Evento event : events)
            users.add(event.getUser());
        return users;
    }

    private void populateEvents() {
        events = new LinkedHashSet<Evento>();
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            FileInputStream fInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fInputStream.read(data);
            fInputStream.close();
            String[] eventsRead = new String(data, "UTF-8").split("\n");
            for (String event : eventsRead)
                events.add(new Evento(event, type));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Nothing really needed.
        }
    }

    /** name field setter */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Requests that the file or directory denoted by this abstract 
     * pathname be deleted when the virtual machine terminates.
     */
    public void setToDeleted() {
        new File(path).deleteOnExit();
    }
}
```

Event:

```
public class Evento implements Comparable<Evento> {

    private LocalDateTime time;
    private LogType type;
    private String event;
    private Utente user;

    public Evento(String event, LogType type) {
        this.event = event;
        this.type = type;
        time = type.getAssociatedLoader().getTimeFromLine(event);
        user = type.getAssociatedLoader().getUserFromLine(event);
    }

    public boolean equals(Evento comparedEvent) {
        return event.equals(comparedEvent.getEvent());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Evento comparedEvent) {
        return event.compareTo(comparedEvent.getEvent());
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public Utente getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return event;
    }
}
```

getTimeFromLine() method:

```
@Override
public LocalDateTime getTimeFromLine(String line) {
    String clockString = line.split("\t")[2];
    return LocalDateTime.of(Integer.parseInt(clockString.substring(0,4)),
            Integer.parseInt(clockString.substring(6,7)),
            Integer.parseInt(clockString.substring(9,10)),
            Integer.parseInt(clockString.substring(11,13)),
            Integer.parseInt(clockString.substring(15,16)),
            Integer.parseInt(clockString.substring(17,19)));
}
```

Lines example (first correctly working, not the latter):

```
142\twestchester.gov\t2006-03-20 03:55:57\t1\thttp://www.westchestergov.com
142\tspace.comhttp\t2006-03-24 20:51:24\t\t
```

Comment: `// Nothing really needed` in your catch? I wouldn't say that.

Comment: Way too much code here. Please learn to present a minimal complete example, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Forming such an example would have answered your own Question, solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not swallow exceptions - if you had let it propagate you would have got a fairly self explanatory exception message that would have helped you find the problem!

   > java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 0

   So one of your `clockString.substring()` does not use the right indices
2. Your `getTimeFromLine` method is unnecessary complicated and I would recommend to use a `DateTimeFormatter` instead of parsing the string manually

Suggested replacement:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

public LocalDateTime getTimeFromLine(String line) {
  String clockString = line.split("\t")[2];
  return LocalDateTime.parse(clockString, fmt);
}
```